# How to include a movie in a PDF? Step by step instructions

Tags: pdftex, media9, acrobat, movie15, multimedia

There are a few question/answers regarding the embedding movies in PDF with pdflatex and special packages. However I find the information dispersed all around and confusing. And so far, in the best cases I get a "3D rendering error in Acrobat Reader" and I don't know what step is failing.

Maybe this particular case serves as guide for a step by step explanation:

- pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian), Acrobat Reader 9.5.1, Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). Need to upgrade something?

1. Let's start with a movie file: `movie.avi` with FFmpeg MPEG-4 encoding. Does it need to be encoded in some other way? what is the best tool to reencode? what encodings are going to work? Is a conversion to `flv` format really necessary?
2. pdflatex: what packages need to be included, `media9`, `movie15` (obsolete?), `flashmovie`?
3. what is the latex command to include the movie? Can one have the option to keep the file inside the PDF or external?
4. How does one get the playback controls rendered with the movie inside the page? Does one really have to use a third party flash-based movie player? If so which player works with Acrobat 9.5.1?
5. Can I expect the movie to be player inside the PDF page in the monitor? Can one expect to have a preview of the movie (first frame) in the static rendering of the page.
6. Can one expect the resulting PDF and embedded movie to work when switching to Windows/Linux/OSX?
7. Does one need to change (hidden?) security preferences in Acrobat to see the movie?

A solution compatible with `beamer` is also desirable.

Comment: For a more specific version of this question, look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux?lq=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> A more specific and updated answer can be found in my answer to
> [Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70931/1871)

- As for production of PDF, no update needed. Sadly, there is no media playback (except for 3D) in AR for linux since v. 9.4.1. It was disabled for obscure reasons. Some opensource PDF viewers on Linux support playback of media that were embedded using `movie15`.

1. Re-encode for use with `media9`: `ffmpeg -i movie.avi -sameq -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25 movie.mp4` or `ffmpeg -i movie.avi -sameq  movie.flv`. For `movie15` there is probably no re-encoding required, but playback mileage may vary on different computers depending on installed media players and codecs.
2. `media9` *or* `movie15`.
3. `media9` and `movie15` physically embed media files into the PDF. `movie15` allows for external files (option `inline=false`). Both allow for media loaded from URLs during runtime.
4. For AR-9/X compatible media (`media9`), playback controls are provided by the media-player Flash-component being used (e. g. `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` or Youtube-URL). AR-9/X compatible media always need a Flash-based media player.
5. Static images can be inserted with `\includegraphics{...}` as the next-to-last argument of `\includemedia` (`media9`) or with `text` option of `\includemovie` (`movie15`).
6. `media9` embeds Flash (SWF), sound (MP3), video (MP4/h.264, FLV) and 3D (PRC, U3D) with  AR-9/X for Win and Mac compatibility. Linux AR-9 only supports embedded 3D. All media files are rendered by the AR built-in FlashPlayer or 3D renderer. Thus, above-mentioned media will *reliably* play on *any* Win and MacOSX box with AR-9 or X installed.

   `movie15` embeds sound, video, Flash and 3D with AR-6/7/8 compatibility. Again, Linux version of AR only supports 3D. Okular, Evince support video playback on Linux. Note that all PDF viewers including AR on Win and Mac depend on third-party media players that must be installed on the host computer. Thus, media file formats and codecs that can be played back highly depend on the available players. The risk of failure is high, in particular in a conference/lecture situation on an unknown computer.
7. `media9`: no; `movie15`: yes

Comment: thanks for the detailed information. Specially the data of step 0. I am already stuck at step 1. First, ffmpeg says it is "deprecated software", Second I get this error: "Failed to set value 'keyint=25'" or (if I remove keyint) "Unknown encoder 'libx264'" (I have libx264 installed in Ubuntu).

Comment: @alfC: ffmpeg is actively developed. Go [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and look for Linux distribution specific information. Alternatively you could use an online service to convert your media files, such as zamzar.com flvencoder.com or mediaconverter.org

Comment: Yes, `ffmpeg` is debian-deprecated probably, it suggests to use `avconv` instead. Still works, I am using ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3. The main problem is that it doesn't recognize the options `-vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25`. Is there an alternative codec? what is exactly the specification of the encoding needed?. If I ran `ffmpeg -codecs` no *264 encoder is reported to be avalable and libx264 doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: @alfC:FLV (Flash Video) as video format will do as well; see my answer. As a last resort, if all fails, use an online service.

Comment: +1 but unfortunately I cannot yet verify that these step by step instructions work, because I don't have access to a system other than linux in which I couldn't make these instructions to work. For a follow up question that I could test and works, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux?lq=1

Comment: As a side note, the `ffmpeg` vs `avconv` issues are the result of a rather nasty political situation leading to a fork, they are (to my understanding) derived from the same code base.

Comment: I didn't know libav & avconv before. Thanks for mentioning it. On my system (Gentoo) I cannot install and try it though. FFmpeg and Libav are mutually blocking.

Comment: @alfC The command `avconv -i profile_test_10.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -keyint_min 25 for_mac_profile_test_10.mp4` produces files that mac's can deal with on debian unstable