# Media9 and non youtube videos

Tags: media9

I've been already in:

1) [Embedding videos using media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102513/embedding-videos-using-media9/102600#102600) Talks about how to embed a file that is already saved in your computer)

2) [Can we use media9 to show a video on a PDF but the video is not embedded to the PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72993/can-we-use-media9-to-show-a-video-on-a-pdf-but-the-video-is-not-embedded-to-the/73039#73039) Gets closer to the solution I'm loking for ---as it uses a local web server---, but when I try to run the "answer" I get an error in the pdf file that says:

> Unable to play
>   'http://www.ted.com/talks/todd_kuiken_a_prosthetic_arm_that_feels.html'

3) [How to include a movie in a PDF? Step by step instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/how-to-include-a-movie-in-a-pdf-step-by-step-instructions/60678#60678) Is more of a discussion about the old and obsolete `movie15` vs the new `media9` package.

4) And, of course, the `media9` [documentation](http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf)
(If you copy-paste the examples you still get errors during compilation)

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{media9}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \includemedia[
    width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,
    activate=onclick,
    flashvars={
       source=http://www.ted.com/talks/todd_kuiken_a_prosthetic_arm_that_feels.html
      &loop=true
    }
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

How do I make [this non youtube video](http://www.ted.com/talks/todd_kuiken_a_prosthetic_arm_that_feels.html) available in my pdf without embedding it and without using a local web server?

Comment: The url you try to pass is not the url of the movie file but the of the page where it resides.

Comment: @PeterJansson I'm sorry, I'm not following.  Could you please write an example of how it should be?

Comment: @MarioS.E. The movie is available at http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011G/None/ToddKuiken_2011G.mp4

Comment: @MarioS.E. at `Download` buttom, just below the movie.

Comment: @Papiro now it's working.  I was missing the "http://" part.  Thanks!  I feel like this question could be closed as being too localized, but at the same time I'm quite aware there is no question regarding how to point to non-youtube videos for `medi9`

Comment: Of which kind were the compilation errors you are referring to in your question? Can you post them?

Answer (score 3):

A non-youtube video, as you may call it, is a URL pointing to an MP4 file on the internet. To be played back, some media player is needed, such as `VPlayer.swf`, and the player `source` FlashVar must be set to the URL of the MP4, such as
`flashvars={source=http://download.ted.com/talks/ToddKuiken_2011G-320k.mp4&loop=true}`. In the original post, `source` is set to some html file which will not work.

Youtube videos, on the other hand, are self-contained media players (in SWF format) which know by themselves where to download the actual MP4 content. There is no source FlashVar to be set. (For completeness, here is the link to [`media9` usage with youtube videos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97687).)